# Is defining the first use of an acronym within parenthesis allowed?

Tags: writing-style

I don't see a rule against it, but defining an acronym within parenthesis does not seem correct (e.g., Awkward Definition of Acronym (ADA)). Does defining ADA like this break rules?

Comment: What do you mean by “allowed”? Allowed by **whom** exactly? This has nothing to do with grammar or grammaticality. It is merely a matter of in-house writing-style guidebooks from this or that publication house. Do you mean according to the *New York Times* Stylebook or the Associated Press Stylebook or the *Chicago Manual of Style* or the *Economist* style guide or the MLA Handbook or the O’Reilly Style Guide or the BBC Style Guide? Or are you just trying to figure out whether it’s according to Hoyle? :)

Comment: @tchrist makes excellent points. The point of writing is to communicate, not to adhere to real or imagined rules. An undefined acronym is careless, uncommunicative, and poor style.

Comment: My style guide of choice suggests brackets inside of parentheses. But since that's messy, it would be better to attach the acronym to a different, non-parenthetical occurrence of *Awkward Definition of Acronym*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [APA](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/10/an-abbreviations-faq.html#Q2), square brackets are used:

> When the spelled-out version first appears in parentheses, put the abbreviation in brackets after it:
>
> - **Example**: The diagnosis (i.e., attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder [ADHD]) was confirmed via behavioral observation.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP isn't asking about a user-defined nonce initialism.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The page I linked explains when it’s acceptable to make up an initialism too. (It doesn’t change the fact that you use square brackets inside the parens when defining it.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You "don't" nest parens, you switch from round brackets to square brackets on the interior.

Comment: @tchrist ? I'm suggesting that OP may be asking asking whether DIY initialisms may be treated in the same way as established (though perhaps little known) initialisms.